# GED/PHP/Zend How to save & generate a pdf that keeps the same hash 

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, hash

i need to first generate a pdf with Zend_Pdf->save('blabla.pdf') to save a pdf file to the system, then:

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('blabla.pdf'); $pdfData = $pdf->render(); 

header("Content-Type: application/x-pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$preuve.".pdf");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

echo $pdfData;
```

to send user the pdf without giving him any link.

then when i want to compare these 2 files with hash_files('sha512','blabla.pdf') and hash_files('sha512','blabladownloadedbyuser.pdf')

and i get 2 different hash.

is there a way to compare 2 pdfs having exactly the same content but generated by 2 different ways.

Edit :

All solutions existing are to 
header("Content-Type: application/x-pdf");
echo blabla;

but this generate a new file each time you regenerate and i need the user to have the exact same file in term of content and be able to control it with a hash.

Thanks
DG

Comment: I would assume that if the headers are different, the file would be different as far as hash is concerned..

Comment: yes i understood that but is there a way to have a hash only on the content of the file ?

Comment: yes, there "sort" of a way to do it , and that would be to save (or cache) the pdf WITH THE HEADERS on the server (Zend_Pdf::save()) and then echo the same PDF that is saved on the server